# Operations on the table - SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php

How to display one element/object = **LAT** from this array and save it to a variable.

```
<?php
$url = "XML";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
?>

//echo $xml->LAT;
//$value = (string) $xml->row[0]->LAT;
//echo $value;
```

Response fields XML:

```
SImpleXMLElement Object ( [row] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [MA] => 310627000 [LAT] => 9.967386 [LON] => 76.269330 ) ) )
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Can you post the whole XML content? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
echo $xml->row[0]['LAT'] . "<br>";
```